# Where to find Ubuntu equivalent packages on Mac OS X

Tags: osx, package-management, homebrew

I using Mac (Sierra OS). As part of a rails project I installed `libwebkitgtk-1.0-0` and `libmagickwand-dev` packages (using `apt-get`) on ubuntu and was looking to do the same on Mac but I can't find them. I tried `brew search` but that didn't yield anything. How do I go about finding and installing the equivalent packages on my MAC device?

Comment: broaden your search - try `brew search webkit` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched:

```
❯ brew search webkitgtk

webkitgtk was deleted from homebrew/core in commit cc9be4ac:
  webkitgtk: migrate to boneyard
  Repeatedly breaks/causes issues & consequently sits there stuck on
  versions with publicly-known CVEs frequently.
  Closes https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/9053.

To show the formula before removal run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" show cc9be4ac^:Formula/webkitgtk.rb

If you still use this formula consider creating your own tap:
  http://docs.brew.sh/How-to-Create-and-Maintain-a-Tap.html
```

---

```
❯ brew search magickwand
homebrew/php/php53-magickwand                     homebrew/php/php55-magickwand
homebrew/php/php54-magickwand                     homebrew/php/php56-magickwand
```

Comment: I got this : brew search webkitgtk.  
No formula found for "webkitgtk".  

Error: curl failed!  
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
curl: (3) <url> malformed.                                                                          For `magickwand` how do I know which of those versions to install? They seem to be for PHP? How did you come up with `magickwand` from `libmagickwand-dev`? And if `webkitgtk` has been deleted then is creating tap the only solution?

Comment: In general, whenever you search for a package, drop the "lib" prefix and the "-dev" suffix. You will find these in lot of packages in Debian / Ubuntu, but these (lib and -dev) are specific to these systems. That's how I came up with "magickwand".

Comment: In relation to webkitgtk, if they dropped it from the repos, the likely reason is that it was being problematic. In this case, you're probably better compiling it from source (i.e. without using a package manager), manually. "Creating a tap", in this context, means to create your own package, but you don't need that much -- and, anyway, you will need to be able to compile it from source before creating your own package.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. When you say compiling from the source is this what you mean - https://webkit.org/building-webkit/ ?                                      Does it make sense to install one of the `php-magickwands` ?                             The bigger question is do I need these packages at all on a MAC?

Comment: "When you say compiling from the source is this what you mean" ==> yes, exactly! Follow that tutorial, it is from the official webkit website. I am not familiar with `magickwand`, is it a library specific to PHP? If yes, then it totally makes sense to install one of the `php-magickwands`. If no, then it means there is no package available for `magickwand`, which means that...you will have to download and build it from source too. If this sounds annoying or complicated, then I would advise you to continue your development in Ubuntu (e.g., with a virtual machine) like you were doing before.

Comment: Thanks again! LOL, the whole point of switching to a MAC was to not require a virtual machine anymore.